# How to align two objects on same line?

Tags: css, css-float, alignment

I'm working on a project which should have two boxes in the upper left hand corner, but then centered text on the same line, seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/charliedean/Gqq6w/23/ . But I'm running into a simple problem with CSS (I'm a novice). The h1 should be aligned center, but the boxes should be in the upper left corner, so here's the code:

```
.box {
margin: 5px;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
float: left;
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;

h1 {
font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
font-size:100px;
color:#fff;
float:center;
```

There's going to be a center aligned jpeg below that. Any help?

Comment: float:center; is not a correct statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `h1` style like this:

```
h1 {
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size:100px;
    color:#fff;
    clear:both;  /*  added  */
    text-align:center;  /*  instead float:center */
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqq6w/30/)

---

**update**: if you want to put them in the same line try like this:

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqq6w/36/)

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="http://google.com"><div class="box">HOME</div></a>
    <a href="http://google.com"><div class="box">HOME</div></a>
</div>
<h1>LEVEL ONE<h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size:100px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.menu{
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've written that, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/charliedean/Gqq6w/35/embedded/result/) is what I come out with. I've gone through all of the help here, but it's still not working quite right; they're not on the same line. Any advice?

Comment: Great! I played with the margins a bit and got it centered on the same line and at the top. But now the image... won't center properly... [see?](http://jsfiddle.net/charliedean/Gqq6w/46/) thanks for all your help already.

Comment: `img` style affected from `h1` style try to add some classes.

Answer (score 0):

Float property have four value in total:left, right, none, and inherit.

***Not Correct***

```
h1 {
font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
font-size:100px;
color:#fff;
float:center;
}
```

Try this:

```
h1 {
font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
font-size:100px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 116px;` property to your h1 selector in your CSS. It will align it with your "box" elements.

(By the way, your HTML is not semantically correct. You can't have a DIV in a A. 
Remove the DIV and add the property `display:inline-block` to your A.)

Comment: You can have a `div` element into an `a` in HTML5 (so you must have an HTML5 doctype). You can even have a heading and 3 paragraphs if you want. This may not be advisable from an accessibility point of view but it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

As GCyrillus said:

> float does not go along with centering since content is not in the regular flow of the page. You may use text-align and display .

Here is a simple solution to place the h1 in center: Place a box with the same width as the two boxes on the right side (let it float:right).

Like:

```
<div class="box">HOME</div><div class="box">HOME</div><div style="float:right; width:200px;"></div><h1>some caption</h1>
```